# DocuSign Previous Signer Information

Tags: docusignapi

How can I pull previous signer information in the body of an email for subsequent signers? We are using embedded signers so none of the signers are known ahead of time. I see that this can be done within the subject but I was wondering if it could be done in the email message body as well.

e.g. - Hello, [Signer 1] has just signed [Document] now it's your turn.

thanks,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing embedded Signers then Signers will not be receiving any email, but even if you want to set any specific subject or emailBody for each recipient, then you can use [recipientEmailNotification](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/recipientEmailNotification) node in your API call once you know who is the signer.

Comment: Actually the 2nd, 3rd, etc. signers will be remote signers Is there a tag similar to the subject heading that can be placed in the body of the email to identify who the previous signer was?

Comment: No, its not available. But as I mentioned in the API, you can always create the emailBody as the way you like by using our API and populating recipientEmailNotification node.